# Meaning of AT commands shortcut

Tags: command, at-command

I just wonder what is actually shortcut AT means. I know alot of AT commands, but what is actual "AT" shortcut? I googled it, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean modem commands - if memory serves - this comes from first letters of `ATtention` [which modem should pay] to command

I do not have any sources, although Wiki seems to agree: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

> The following text lists part of the Hayes command set (also called
>   the AT commands: "AT" meaning attention).

Answer (score 1):

AT stands for `ATtention`. It is a way of interacting with the modem. Every command line starts with "AT" or "at". They are called AT commands because the
characters AT must precede each command to get the ATtention of the modem

As already told by wmz, you can find more about it here:
[AT Commands - WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set)

**Command**: AT Attention Code

**Values**: n/a

**Description**: The attention code precedes all command lines except A/, A: and escape sequences.